# Fuse - fabric:container-add-profile:from where does this command import profiles

Tags: jboss, esb, jbossfuse

In Fuse we can add profiles to container using command *fabric:container-add-profile*.Where are these profiles stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean physical location, look for profiles in folder:

```
/fabric/configs/versions/1.0/profiles
```

You can consider also to use [Hawtio](http://hawt.io/) as a very convenient tool with web interface to manage profiles, containers, bundles, etc.